# Not existing column in the current network's table but still visible in the column selection

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I have imported data table to my cytoscape map for the following continuous mapping accorging to values. After some time, I have imported another data table and then deleted the previous one. The original data are not present in either the node or edge table but I still can see the names of the original columns when selecting column for continuous mapping i. g. for size or colour. Moreover, this warning appears: "The current table does not have the selected column. Please select another column." Do you know how to solve this so that I no longer see the names when these columns are not even in the table?
I would be grateful for any ideas.

I have tried to delete the data table and import the data again but it didn't help. I have also tried to clone current network and import data to the new map, but the old names are still present in the column selection.
Do you know how to solve this so that I no longer see the names when these columns are not even in the table?

I would be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

A couple points and then a couple suggestions:

- The style is going to "remember" the selected column name, even if you delete it since it doesn't know what to change it to. It will add a warning icon mentioning that the column is missing. You have to choose a new column (or reload the missing column) to address that issue. [I think you know this already, but just stating for completeness :)]
- The pulldown list of column names *should* be updated when you delete table columns. This does indeed sound like a bug.

  - Are you running the latest Cytoscape 3.9.1?
  - Have you tried selecting another style and then returning back to this style? That might "refresh" the column name list.
  - Have you tried saving/restoring the session?

Comment: Yes, I have the last version of Cytoscape

Yes and yes, I have also tried these options.

Of course, the last thing I can do is to make a totally new session and set the whole style again and then import the current data. But this is something I would really like to avoid.

Comment: If you want to share your .cys file with Cytoscape developers, feel free to report a bug and attach the file.